# iif on tsql dont return expected result

Tags: t-sql

I have and issue in my query don't return correct data when I compare some values

```
select a.item, iif(a.value>b.value,0,1) as compare 
from table a left join table b on a.id=b.id
```

return

```
item1, 0
item2, 0
item3, 0
```

and my data is

```
table a 
item1 10
item2 20
item3 30

table b
item1 5
item2 25
item3 30
```

expected correct result was

```
item1, 0
item2, 1
item3, 0
```

and when I use ISNULL() function return

```
item1, 1
item2, 1
item3, 1
```

happened the same problem with CASE WHEN ... THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

I really don't know what's happened with the query I don't find where is the problem any help very thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update your question so the tables include the data in the Id column?

Comment: The expect result is item1, 0; item2,1; item3, 1

Comment: I use just figurate example but the error has in my join very thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be Inner join and using [for spaced table names or columns]

```
SELECT
  a.item,
  iif(a.value > b.value, 0, 1) AS compare
FROM [table a] a
INNER JOIN [table b] b
  ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're joining the same table onto itself, i.e.:

```
table a
```

This refers to a table called 'table', aliased as 'a'.

If you are joining the same table onto itself, this will account for your result of everything returning 1, as, assuming a one-to-one match, `a.value` and `b.value` will always be equal.

Are you looking for something more like:

```
[table a] a left join [table b] b on a.id = b.id
```